# scala future null pointer match error

Tags: scala, mapping, future, flatmap, playframework-webservice

New to scala futures I try to call a web service like

```
wsClient.url(baseUrl + url).withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json").post(dataForR).flatMap(parseOutlierResponse)
```

using `ply-ws` library

I validate & map the response as follows https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/943a18d43279762ad4cdfe9aa2e40770

The main thing is:

```
Await.result(callAMethodCallingTheFirstSnippet, 5.minutes)
```

Strangely this **works just fine in the repl**. However if run via `sbt run` I get a NullPointer Exception. I already verified the JSON response manually. It validates like a breeze. Even the mapping works great. However, there must be a problem with the futures I am using. But I am not sure what is wrong. It seems like the **flatMap method is called before** there already is a result.

Interestingly if I **do not await the result** there is no null-pointer exception, but the parsed result is displayed **correctly** (however, the program does not exit). But there, where I really use this code, I somehow need to await the successful completion to further deal with it.

Below you will find an illustration of the problem

[image: How can the response body be null?]

Comment: Sounds like there is no response JSON. Did you try printing out the response body?

Comment: As mentioned above when run in the REPL it really works and the `Await.result(result, 10.minutes)` maps the response just fine. So yes there is a response when printed like `wsClient.url(baseUrl + url).withHeaders("Content-Type" -> "application/json").post(dataForR).map(response => println(response.body))`

Comment: I used the printed response.body to obtain the data. Then again the mapping works great `val dataP = Json.parse(manuallyExtractedData).validate[Seq[OutlierPortal]].fold(
      error => {
        println(s"Unable to parse response: $error")
        Future.failed(new RuntimeException("parse-json-failed"))
      },
      outlierResponse => Future.successful(outlierResponse.map {
        _.toMap
      })
    )
    dataP.foreach(println)`

Comment: @sparkr please see the minimum example and the latest screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more and more debugging I found that some implicits were in the wrong scope and the order of dependent case-classes was wrong. After moving them into the correct scope (the method performing the request) the null-pointer exception is fixed.

I could only find the "real" error after changing from `flatmap` to `map` which I find very strange. However, now both methods work fine.

Comment: Just wondering, why do you wrap the results in `parseOutlierResponse` using Future.successful. This looks superfluous, you can just throw the exceptions and `map` the `post()`.

Comment: Well starting out with futures I based my approach on https://github.com/studiodev/Mocky/blob/master/app/services/GithubRepository.scala and they use it like that. But I understand your point now.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see any major concern with your code! I made a small test with the following code bit and it seems to be working perfectly, both in the REPL and when using sbt run:

```
    WS.clientUrl(s"http://$hostName/api/put").withHeaders(jsonHeaders: _*).post(body).map { r =>
      if (r.status >= 400)
        logger.warn(s"Invalid http response status: ${r.status} \n ${r.body}")
      else
        logger.debug(s"Successfully persisted data. Http response ${r.status}")
    }
```

Comment: indeed your code prints the response. However if the mapping like `r.json.validate[Seq[OutlierPortal]].fold(
          error => {
            println(s"Unable to parse response: $error")
            (new RuntimeException("parse-json-failed"))
          },
          outlierResponse => outlierResponse.map {
            _.toMap
          }` is added I get the null pointer from above.